# onclick function on radio cannot trigger second one at first click

Tags: javascript, css

I have two radio type inputs.
I want background change its color when radio switch to different input.

As the pic downbelow, 
[image]

I met a problem that while click first one it can change color immediately,
but click second can not change at first click.

I need to click two times in second one to change its color.

```html
<div class="o_field_radio o_vertical o_field_widget o_required_modifier in_out bg" name="in_out" style="width:70px;">
    <div class="o_radio_item">
        <input class="o_radio_input" type="radio" data-index="0" data-value="I" id="radio1032_I">
        <label class="o_form_label" for="radio1032_I">進貨</label>
    </div>

    <div class="o_radio_item">
        <input class="o_radio_input" type="radio" checked="true" data-index="1" data-value="O" id="radio1032_O">
        <label class="o_form_label" for="radio1032_O">出貨</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var bg = $('.bg');
// check-box value decide background-color.
$(document).on('click', "div[name='in_out']", function(event){
    var v = $("div[name='in_out'] div input:checked").attr('data-value');
    if (v =='O') {
        bg.css("background-color","#adff2f");
    }
    else if(v =='I') {
        bg.css("background-color","#ffc0cb");
    }
});
```

Do anyone knows how to solve this error?

Comment: What happens whe  you click on the second button first?

Comment: it won't change colors. I need to click two time to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any element with class `bg` in the markup. You also should group them by setting the name attribute.

***The html document is generate by framework ODOO. So I can not change its name attribute***

If you are not able to change the HTML manually then you can set the *name* attribute on document ready

You can try the following way:

```js
// Set the name attribute on document ready
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.bg .o_radio_input').attr('name', 'myRadio');
});

var bg = $('.bg');
// check-box value decide background-color.
$(document).on('click', "div[name='in_out']", function(event){
    var v = $("div[name='in_out'] div input:checked").attr('data-value');
    if (v =='O') {
        bg.css("background-color","#adff2f");
    }
    else if(v =='I') {
        bg.css("background-color","#ffc0cb");
    }
});
$('div[name=in_out]').trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="o_field_radio o_vertical o_field_widget o_required_modifier in_out bg" name="in_out" style="width:70px;">
    <div class="o_radio_item">
        <input class="o_radio_input" type="radio" data-index="0" data-value="I" id="radio1032_I">
        <label class="o_form_label" for="radio1032_I">進貨</label>
    </div>

    <div class="o_radio_item">
        <input class="o_radio_input" type="radio" checked="true" data-index="1" data-value="O" id="radio1032_O">
        <label class="o_form_label" for="radio1032_O">出貨</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do have, but I just miss it.

Comment: @TerrencePoe, the above solution shows that the code is working by setting the *name* attribute:)

Comment: thank you, I found I miss some info, and I reply it on new post.

Answer (score 1):

First thing , you need to have same name for radio buttons. Secondly you may not need this line `$(document).on('click', "div[name='in_out']", function(event){` since the elements are not dynamically loaded.So no need to delegate it from the document. Also  `var v = $("div[name='in_out'] div input:checked").attr('data-value');` line will be redundant. Besides you can have the color as the data-attribute of the radio button & use `change` instead of click. So on `change` get the data attribute and set it using `.css`

```js
var bg = $('.bg');
// check-box value decide background-color.
$('.o_radio_input').on('change', function(event) {
  bg.css("background-color", $(this).data('color'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="o_field_radio o_vertical o_field_widget o_required_modifier in_out bg" style="width:70px;">
  <div class="o_radio_item">
    <input name="in_out" class="o_radio_input" type="radio" data-index="0" data-value="I" id="radio1032_I" data-color='#adff2f'>
    <label class="o_form_label" for="radio1032_I">進貨</label>
  </div>

  <div class="o_radio_item">
    <input name="in_out" class="o_radio_input" type="radio" checked="true" data-index="1" data-value="O" id="radio1032_O" data-color="#ffc0cb">
    <label class="o_form_label" for="radio1032_O">出貨</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I will try onchange method later. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I miss some info:

1.The html document is generate by framework ODOO. So I can not change its name atrribute.
the view template is deploy by xml document.
the origin code is looks like this:

```xml
<field class="in_out" name="in_out" widget="radio"/>
```

2. the div is wrap by a div class='bg', I just miss it.
3. In order to show more clearly, I add alert function.
   It will show you message while you click.

```js
var bg = $('.bg')
// check-box value decide background-color.
$(document).on('click', "div[name='in_out']", function(event){
    alert('clicked');
    let v = $("div[name='in_out'] div input:checked").attr('data-value');
    if (v =='O') {
        bg.css("background-color","#adff2f");
    }
    else if(v =='I') {
        bg.css("background-color","#ffc0cb");
    }
});
$('div[name=in_out]').trigger('click');
```

and the result looks like this:
[image]

Mamun's script is working well here.
But when it runs on ODOO, it will work as the pic.

Comment: You can set the *name* attribute on document ready, please check my updated answer:)